# Vaadin tree expand animation issue

Tags: java, css, vaadin7

I'm using vaadin's tree in my web application and everything is OK till I add expand animation to tree. I'm adding animation via css like this:

```
$v-tree-expand-animation-enabled: true;
```

The animation works but when expanding or collapsing items a problem appears:
[image]

Has anyone ever had this problem and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a Vaadin bug. If you use the newest version you can create a bug report on https://dev.vaadin.com/